# Form builder em elemento da dropbox

Tags: angular, formulário

Tenho o seguinte form group:

createFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      descricao: '',
      valor: '',
      sku: '',
      tipo: '',
    });
  }

onde: 'tipo' deveria vir o valor da dropdown.

Minha drop:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-group waves-effect" 
       type="button" id="dropdownTipoVariacao"
       data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       {{categoriaForm.value.variacoes.tipo == null ? 'Tipo De Variação' : categoriaForm.value.variacoes.tipo }}
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
       <h6 class="dropdown-header">Tipo de Variação</h6>
       <a formControlName="tipo" name="dropvariacao{{i}}" (click)="setTipoVariacao(i,tipoVariacao.nome)" *ngFor="let tipoVariacao of tiposvariacoes;let j = index"
       class="dropdown-item">{{tipoVariacao.nome}}</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Acontece que eu recebo:

> No value accessor for form control with name: 'tipo'

Li que somente inputs podem receber formControlName.

Então, tentei adicionar a função:

```
(click)="setTipoVariacao(i,tipoVariacao.nome)"

  setTipoVariacao(index: number, nome: string){
    this.categoriaForm.value.variacoes[index].tipo = nome
  }
```

Se eu printar na tela o resultado em execução ele até adiciona o valor, porém quando eu digito algum valor em algum campo do meu formControl ele apaga o tipo do array:

```
{ "descricao": "fsafasfasf", "valor": "", "sku": "", "tipo": "" }
```

Como contornar essa situação?

Answer (score 0):

Se alguém passar por isso, troque o dropdown por um select:

```
<select formControlName="tipo" class="form-control" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
   <h6 class="dropdown-header">Tipo de Variação</h6>
   <option *ngFor="let tipoVariacao of tiposvariacoes;let j = index"
   class="dropdown-item">{{tipoVariacao.nome}}</option>
</select>
```

O select possui suporte para o formControlName e funciona como esperado.